# Error while displaying records from external storage to listview

Tags: android, android-listview

Im having problem while displaying .mp3 files from external storage to the listview. Im getting error with "ArrayAdapter requires a resource ID to be a TextView". All is set but dont know why this is happening. Below is the source code, please help me out!

"Activity_main.xml"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testproject.MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@id/android:list" >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/stop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

"list.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt1"
                    android:layout_width="309dp"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </GridLayout>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

"MainActivity.java"

```
package com.example.testproject;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;


class mp3filter implements FilenameFilter{


    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {

        return filename.endsWith(".mp3");
    }

}
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String SD_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/");
    private List<String> voice = new ArrayList<String>();
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    Button btn;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        updatePlayList();

        btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mp.stop();

            }
        });
    }
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        try{
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + voice.get(position));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void updatePlayList() {

        File home = new File(SD_PATH);
        if(home.listFiles(new mp3filter()).length>0)
        {
            for(File file: home.listFiles(new mp3filter()))
                {
                voice.add(file.getName());
                }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> voiceList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list,voice);
        setListAdapter(voiceList);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `ArrayAdapter<String>` need an `TextView` to show value, you can see the implement code of [`ArrayAdapter getView method`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.getView%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%29). However your `list` layout is so complicated as the input. So you can choose one of these options below:

1. Try to change `R.layout.list` to
   `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and test again
2. Create
   `YourCustomAdapterClass extends ArrayAdapter` and figure out the
   `TextView` in `getView()` method. Sample from [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)
3. Create`YourCustomAdapterClass extends BaseAdapter`. Sample from [here](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/)

Update code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + voice.get(position));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void updatePlayList() {

        File home = new File(SD_PATH);
        File[] fileList = home.listFiles(new mp3filter());
        if (fileList.length > 0) {
            for (File file : fileList) {
                voice.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> voiceList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, voice);
        setListAdapter(voiceList);

    }
```

Comment: well that's a pretty good help though, yet i'm confused that how do i display the .mp3 file names on ListView.

Comment: What are you confusing now? Have you try option 1 yet? Try it and give me your next problem with that.

Comment: I tried the first one, it didn't stop this time, but did not even display anything except the button.  and the rest two options u provided, i gone through that was well understandable, but i'm confused that how do i use it, what variable should i be passing to display the results.

Comment: Are you sure that `voice` is not empty after the `for` loop?

Comment: well it was giving an error of "null pointer exception" b4, but now after some update its just restricted to the error i mentioned in the question.

Comment: You did not answer my question that the `voice` list is empty or not? If you get another errors, so update your question again, and also put the `Error log`.

Comment: Oh yes! I've just printed the files in Toast, and they are displaying the file names. here is what i've done                                                                  
ArrayAdapter<String> voiceList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
   setListAdapter(voiceList);
   Toast.makeText(this, ""+voice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: No, you're just displayed the object `voice`, not the `size` of it. Try `Toast.makeText(this, "voice size"+voice.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. If = 0, then nothing is show in your `listview`.

Comment: Perfectly displaying the result as 3. and there are exactly three files stored in the external storage.

Comment: Hey John! Special Thanks to you my friend! You did a fantastic job :)

Comment: But here comes the other issue, after copying .apk file to my phone, its not displaying me anything :/

Comment: Ofcause my friend, because your code just find the `.mp3` files from the `SD_Card parent folder` only, and I think your music files not here, don't they?. You need research more [android find all mp3 files](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20find%20all%20mp3%20files) . Hope that help!